# Use a Mustache template from a Maven dependency

Tags: java, model-view-controller, classpath, mustache

I have several user-facing, Java microservices that render screens via [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) templates. I also have a self-made Maven library which - among other things - holds a cookie banner Mustache template.

Currently, that cookie banner Mustache template from the library is hard coded into each of the individual microservices, because the developers that created the library were not aware of a way to "import" Mustache templates.

I would like to "import" the cookie banner Mustache template from the library instead, to keep the code DRY and more maintainable.

Is there a way that you can use a Mustache template from a Maven dependency?

Thus far, I have been trying to load the template from the classpath, to no avail. Even if this were to succeed, I would not know how to then reference that template in another template to use it as a partial.

Documentation for Mustache is quite scarce and the examples are often simple use-cases, replies are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem you would like to share a template across multiple jars correct?

If so an easy way to do that is to make a core jar with all the templates in them and I recommend models as well.

I'm the author of [JStachio a Java mustache templating engine](https://github.com/jstachio/jstachio) and you can easily do the above by creating [JStaches which are just a model and template glued together](https://jstach.io/doc/jstachio/current/apidocs/io.jstach.jstache/io/jstach/jstache/JStache.html).

You then put all your JStaches in a shared jar. Share the jar with all the microservices.

It's important to understand that the model aka the class annotated with JStache is essentially the contract of the template which IMO is critical if you are sharing the template which is why I'm shamefully pushing my library here because none of the other mustache java implementations do that.